# Remove delay when running script on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently having trouble with removing delay from my website when I run a function on page load. Is there any way to run a function before page load? Here is the code I am trying to run:

```
function OnLoad()
if (Cookies.get('Theme') === 'OFF') 
{
$("body").removeClass("dark");
$(".inner-switch").text("OFF");
} else if (Cookies.get('Theme') === 'ON') {
$("body").addClass("dark");
$(".inner-switch").text("ON");
} else {
var Theme;
}
}
```

And this is how I am running it at page load.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<title>Will's Site</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/navbar.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body onload="OnLoad()">
<!-- Nav Bar -->

<!-- Content -->


<!-- Scripts -->
<script src="js/jquery-3.4.1.js">  </script>
<script src="js/dark-mode.js"></script>
<script src="js/navbar.js"></script>
<script src="js/js.cookie.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

If you need more resources here is the GitHub for the website: [My GitHub Link](https://github.com/wrssmithjr04/wrssmithjr04.github.io)

Comment: Try placing your script just before the closing `</body>` tag... but not in a function, just the script. That way the elements your script is accessing will be available

Comment: Alternatively, have a script just before the closing `</body>` which calls your function... e.g. `<script>OnLoad();</script></body>`.  On either of these options you should remove the `onload="OnLoad()"` from the opening `<body>` tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are using jQuery so you could execute your code when the DOM is ready to be manipulated using jQuery's ready event which also adds crossbrowser combatibility.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 if (Cookies.get('Theme') === 'OFF') 
 {
   $("body").removeClass("dark");
   $(".inner-switch").text("OFF");
 } else if (Cookies.get('Theme') === 'ON') {
   $("body").addClass("dark");
   $(".inner-switch").text("ON");
 } else {
   var Theme;
 }
});
```

Also remove the onLoad from the body tag and place this code inside an inline or external script after jQuery

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use a server side script like php

`<body class="<?php if( !empty( $_COOKIE[ 'theme' ] ) && $_COOKIE[ 'theme' ] == 'ON' ) { echo "dark" } ?>">`

So the code is direktly rendering the right theme.